# SplitString vs Split difference

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Consider this sample program comparing [StrUtils.SplitString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString) and [SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split):

```
Program Test;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
Uses
  System.SysUtils,System.Types,StrUtils;

var
  s: String;
  a: TArray<String>; 
  b: TStringDynArray;
begin
  s := ':';
  a := s.Split([':']);  
  WriteLn(Length(a)); 
  b := SplitString(s,':');
  WriteLn(Length(b));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The output is:

```
1
2
```

Can anyone explain the difference?

I would expect that the result is 2 empty strings.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for the link. I'm puzzled by the quality of the RTL. Basic functions has to tested and retested. I'll see if this is reported to QP, otherwise I'll submit a new issue.

Comment: It's depressing. Testing a split function is all about corner cases. And the symmetry argument in the dupe's answer should have been used in the design and the testing.

Comment: Bug report filed, https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11302 "TStringHelper.Split disfunctional".